# How to add a legend in a pandas DataFrame scatter plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains the following columns of interest:

```
['Relative Width', 'Relative Height', 'Object Name', 'Object ID']
```

There are 15 object names with 15 colors determined with `df.plot(c='Object ID')` that produce the following figure:

[image: fig]

I want to display a legend with the 15 object names, how this can be done?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from annotation_parsers import parse_voc_folder


def visualize_box_relative_sizes(folder_path, voc_conf, cache_file='data_set_labels.csv'):
    frame = parse_voc_folder(folder_path, voc_conf, cache_file)
    title = f'Relative width and height for {frame.shape[0]} boxes.'
    frame.plot(
        kind='scatter',
        x='Relative Width',
        y='Relative Height',
        title=title,
        c='Object ID',
        colormap='gist_rainbow',
        colorbar=False,
    )
    plt.show()
```

Based on wwnde recommendation, I changed the code to the following:

```
def visualize_box_relative_sizes(folder_path, voc_conf, cache_file='data_set_labels.csv'):
    frame = parse_voc_folder(folder_path, voc_conf, cache_file)
    title = f'Relative width and height for {frame.shape[0]} boxes.'
    sns.scatterplot(x=frame["Relative Width"], y=frame["Relative Height"], hue=frame["Object Name"])
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: what is `parse_voc_folder`? can you stub that out for us?

Comment: probably have to go this route - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812325/pandas-scatter-plot-with-different-color-legend-for-each-point

Comment: @DerekEden I tried the approach on the dataframe I have which has 10,000 rows, It took like 30 seconds running without giving any results so I think it's a pretty inefficient approach.

Comment: @Z4-tier I don't want to complicate things here, anyway it's a function that returns a dataframe with 8 columns, 4 of which I mentioned above and they are the columns of interest, the rest of the dataframe is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: if it was done correctly there would definitely be results, it's just looping and doing 1 scatter point at a time, though I agree it's not an efficient approach. Might be able to do some kind of work around like getting all the unique Object IDs and their respective colors, just looping over those at the end and adding labels so a legend can be added, or maybe creating a custom legend https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html ....maybe generate a color column before plotting that you can use for either of those two ideas

Comment: Why not  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Relative Width", y="Relative Height",
                     hue="Relative Height", size="size",
                     data=tips)
plt.show()   ? and this will give you a legend and default allocated colours?

Comment: @wwnde I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
                     hue="size", size="size",
                     data=tips)
ax.set_title('title')
plt.show()
```

This should give you a default coloured legend

Comment: I tried this approach and it worked, I'll edit my question to include the results, how can I modify the cmap for this setup?

Comment: @sK500 add the parameter `palette = 'gist_rainbow'`