# How to plot every label once in matplotlib legend with corresponding color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, legend

How can I only show a name once in the legend with corresponding color instead of index?

```
data = {'x':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'y':[4, 3, 2, 1, 0], 
        'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Emma'],
        'Color':['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'green']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color = df['Color'], label = df['Name'])
plt.legend()
```

[image]

I know this can be done with `Seaborn`, but I prefer to do it in `Matplotlib` (and without a for-loop).

Comment: Plot each point individually as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37813290/8881141)

Comment: @Mr.T Isn't there a way to do it without looping? I know this is possible in Seaborn, but I'd like to do it in matplotlib directly

Comment: Matplotlib only supports one label per call to `scatter`.  Luckily you can use seaborn or a loop to solve the problem.

Comment: @JohanC So does Seaborn then perform the loop internally? What would the loop look like in my case, given that I already have a column with the designated colors?

Comment: Your process is a bit unusual.  Normally, you have some code that would have created the `'Color'` column from the names, e.g. using a dictionary.  In this case, you need to reconstruct the dictionary from the dataframe, e.g. `color_dict = {name: color for name, color in zip(df['Name'], df['Color'])}`. Then you can use `sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='Name', palette=color_dict)`.  Or with a loop: `for name in df['Name'].unique(): plt.scatter('x', 'y', data=df[df['Name']==name], color=color_dict[name], label=name)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

`df.pivot(index='x', values='y', columns='Name').plot(style='.', markersize=15)`

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for your sugesstion! However, how can I plot this if I don't want to directly put .plot behind it but rather create a new plt.plot()? Also, now the colors from the color column are not incorporated.

Comment: You could sort the df for unique names, then get the corresponding colors list, and provide it to the plot function as `color=retrieved_colorlist`. Please be aware that although this plot looks like a scatter plot, it is indeed a line plot without lines. Depending on what you intend to do with this plot afterward, the code might behave differently.